# jQuery Continuous fadein fadeout Loop

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of code, right now it only runs once.. I need it to run continiously once the dom is loaded for the user. not sure how to go about this... thanks.

```
$('.first').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('.second').fadeIn();
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JavaScript `setInterval` function and do:

```
setInterval(delayFunction, 8000);

function delayFunction() {
   $('.first').fadeOut('slow', function() {
       $('.second').fadeIn();
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the elements to fade out as well. If dnot then only go one level deep then call the function again.

```
$(document).ready(fadeIn);

function fadeRepeat()
{
    $('.first').delay(8000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $('.second').fadeIn(function() {
                $('.first').fadeIn('slow', function() {
                     $('.second').fadeOut(fadeRepeat());
                }
          });
    });
}
```

Comment: this works but it's a big glitchy, the 2nd image still appears for a second then disapears

Comment: Not sure why without seeing it in action. Can you post your html snippet?

Comment: I can PM you the link privately, i can't post it here.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
     $('.first').fadeOut('slow', function() {
     $('.second').fadeIn()
 });
}, 8000);
```